# Angular Animations resetting styling when finished

Tags: javascript, css, angular, css-animations

I am currently creating some Angular animations. I am triggering the animation on a div which consists of a list. When the animation is triggered I want to collapse the list and then slide the whole div out of the viewport. My issue is that the `height` of the list is resetted when the animation for the parent div is triggered.

My code looks like the following:

```js
trigger('removeAnimation', [
  transition(':leave', [
    query('.container', animate('1s ease-in', style({ height: 0 })
    )),
    animate('1s ease-in', keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)', offset: 0.33 }),
      style({ transform: 'translate3d(-150%, 0, 0)', opacity: 0, offset: 0.66 }),
      style({ transform: 'translate3d(-150%, 0, 0)', opacity: 0, height: 0, offset: 1.0 })
    ]))
  ])
])
```

After the query for `.container` has finished and before the `animate` block is executed, the `.container`'s height is restored to its' start height. Then it performs the `animate`.

How do I keep the new `height`? I tried to add a `style` between `query` and `animate` and that works as a workaround. However, I do not know the `height` of the parent at all times.

Edit: I figured out a "workaround". You can add the following after the query to force the div to re-set its' height without the (now missing) child div:

```js
style({ height: 'auto' })
```

For me this will work for now but only because my changes are so small. If I were to animate multiple things inside of the query I guess it would be a lot harder to maintain like that.